# Sqlalchemy subqueries with Python

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, psql

How can I transform this query to use with SQLAlchemy, or is it better to use raw queries for this?

```sql
select ae.performed_by_id as user_uid, (
    select count(distinct ae2.performed_by_id)
    from analytic_events ae2
    where ae2.user_id = ae.performed_by_id
    and ae2.event_type = 'SEEN_NEARBY'
    and ae2.created_at::date = now()::date
) seen_by_people_count,
(
    select count(ae2.performed_by_id)
    from analytic_events ae2
    where ae2.user_id = ae.performed_by_id
    and ae2.event_type = 'SEEN_NEARBY'
    and ae2.created_at::date = now()::date
) total_times_seen
from analytic_events ae
where ae.event_type = 'SEEN_NEARBY'
and ae.created_at::date = now()::date
group by ae.performed_by_id
```

Comment: [SqlAlchemy.core expression API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/expression_api.html) can do any complex query including your query (I'm using it with complex queries on a software at my work). You can read [the tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html) (I strong recommend this) or wait if someone can 'translate'. I prefer use SqlAlchemy since I can use variables to store some parts of query.